# Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shinydashboard

I am getting an error: argument "x" is missing, with no default
Upon debugging, I found this out to be in the line :
**`MyData1<- MyData()[,c(col(),col()+1)]`**
I have tried to pass the argument as a single vector like 
**`MyData1<- MyData()[,p=c(col(),col()+1)]`**

> Error: Error in [.data.frame: unused argument (p = c(col(), col() +
>   1))

This is just a snippet from my actual code:

```
TotalTS<-ts(MyData()[,Col()],start=Start(),frequency = Fre())
    InsampleTs<-window(TotalTS,start = c(Start(),1),end=c(2017,5))
    TotalTS1<-ts(MyData()[,Col()+1],start=Start(),frequency = Fre())
    InsampleTs1<-window(TotalTS1,start = c(Start(),1),end=c(2017,5))

    MyData1<- MyData()[,c(col(),col()+1)]
    MyData1$util1<-MyData1[,1]*100/MyData1[,2]
    popj<-nrow(MyData())-length(InsampleTs)


    if(input$F6==1){
      if(input$AM==1){

        forecast32<-hw(InsampleTs,h=Col1(),level = input$CI2)
        forecast32_1<-hw(InsampleTs,h=Col1(),level = input$CI2)

        c<-as.matrix(forecast32$x)
        d<-as.matrix(forecast32_1$x)

        c1<-as.matrix(forecast32$fitted)
        d1<-as.matrix(forecast32_1$fitted)
        util2<-(c1*100)/d1
        util1<-(c*100)/d
        c11 <- as.matrix(forecast32$mean[1:popj])
        d11<- as.matrix(forecast32_1$mean[1:popj])
        c12 <- as.matrix(forecast32$lower[1:popj])
        d12<- as.matrix(forecast32_1$lower[1:popj])
        c13 <- as.matrix(forecast32$upper[1:popj])
        d13<- as.matrix(forecast32_1$upper[1:popj])

        c111 <- c11*100/d11
      c112<- c12*100/d12
        c113 <- c13*100/d13
        MyData1$util2 <- util2
        MyData1 <- MyData1[,c(col(),col()+1)]

        e<-as.matrix(forecast32$mean[-c(1:popj)])
        f<-as.matrix(forecast32_1$mean[-c(1:popj)])
        e2<-as.matrix(forecast32$upper[-c(1:popj)])
        f2<-as.matrix(forecast32_1$upper[-c(1:popj)])
        e1<-as.matrix(forecast32$lower[-c(1:popj)])
        f1<-as.matrix(forecast32_1$lower[-c(1:popj)])

        e111 <- e*100/f
        e113<- e2*100/f2
        e112 <- e1*100/f1

       r<- cbind(e111,e112,e113)
       colnames(r) <- c("Predicted","lower Limit","Upper Limit")

        MyData1 <- ts(MyData1,start=c(Start(),1), end=c(2017,5), frequency=Fre())
        #r<-ts(r,start=c(2017,6),end=c((Hstar()+2),Fre()))
        r<-ts(r,start=c(2017,6),end=c(2019,6), frequency = 12)
        autoplot(ts( cbind(r,MyData1),start = c(Start(),1),frequency=Fre() ),facets = F)
        }**strong text**
```

Comment: What is `col()`? Is that a function you wrote? Is that a reactive object? It's not clear from your code chunk. Please make sure you provide a [reproducible example]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example() with your question that include sample data that we can actually run and test.

Comment: Yes, Col() is a reactive object. Even upon trying to manually feed in numbers it is giving the same error.

Comment: You've defined both `col()` and `Col()`? (R is case sensitive).

Comment: MyData() is the table one gets to upload, and Col() is the option given to input the column number, one wishes to explore.

Comment: `col` is a function in base R. So when you use `col()`, that function is looking for an argument `x` and not finding it. I suggest using more descriptive variable names or storing all your reactive values in a `reactiveValues(...)` list.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code and tracing the sequence of steps to `MyData1`, I identified these lines:

```
  1 c1<-as.matrix(forecast32$fitted)
  2 d1<-as.matrix(forecast32_1$fitted)
  3 util2<-(c1*100)/d1
  4 MyData1$util2 <- util2
  5 MyData1 <- MyData1[,c(col(),col()+1)]
```

Assuming `MyData` is an object which already exists as a matrix or data.frame, the issue is because you are not giving the `Extract` operator an index specifying the rows or column you wish to extract. Instead you've passed the `col` function without specifying a matrix-like object for it to use.

```
 5 MyData1 <- MyData1[,c(col(),col()+1)]
```

Should Be

```
5 MyData1 <- MyData1[,c(col(x),col(x)+1)]
```

However, I must ask, what are you trying to accomplish with this subset operation? There maybe a more elegant and compact solution that is cleaner than using the `col` function to specify the columns you'd like to extract from MyData1.